# Hurum, anrã, aham, mhm, ãrrã

Tags: uso-de-palavras, interjeições

Descobri, há pouco, grafias alternativas para a interjeição de concordância que eu somente conhecida como *aham*.

Em particular, eu me espantei com *hurum*, utilizada, ao que pude perceber, em algum lugar de Portugal (eu falo pt-br).

Em quais países ou lugares elas são utilizadas? Existem outras grafias?

Comment: Eu esqueci de mencionar que sou do Rio de Janeiro, Brasil

Comment: Dessas só conhecia *aham*. Pessoalmente uso apenas *hum-hum*, ou de Lisboa falante pt_PT

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos, transforma teu comentário em uma resposta por favor e acrescenta mais detalhes! Eu votaria nela com satisfação.

Comment: Boas transformaria com gosto, mas isto é apenas um curto comentário pessoal, acho que não classifica como resposta completa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minha mãe é da região Beira Interior de Portugal, ela fala muito *"hurum"* (não sei se essa é a forma certa da grafia).

Contudo, nós moramos em Goiás e por aqui é uma expressão extremamente comum. Inclusive, para seu registro, encontrei até uma monografia da UEG, [*Falares rurais e falares urbanos: contatos e influências*](http://cdn.ueg.edu.br/arquivos/jussara/conteudoN/1208/Monografia,_Debora.pdf), em que a formanda fez o uso da expressão na dissertação (p. 66):

> **Informante 1:** Aqui pá pessoa de idade é mai maiô, assim iguali o meu é inaceitável, num tem jeito num tem comu, só se eu fô sadi. Sô si ele fô sadi pá ele, fica na roça.
> **Pesquisadora:** Hurum.
> **Informante 1:** Igual o seu Dico Otávio agora cê vai lá, seu Dico Otávio num tem saúde mai ele mora na fazenda. Cê vai na casa dele ou ele mora aqui na rua?
> **Pesquisadora:** Não eu vou.
> **Informante 1:** Ele mora aqui na rua né?
> **Pesquisadora:** Humrum.

Comment: Capaz de *hurum* ter sido erro de digitação, já que há apenas uma ocorrência de *hurum* contra 19 de *humrum*

Answer (score 5):

Nunca parei para pensar na grafia dessas interjeições. O que vejo, principalmente em conversas informais escritas - WhatsApp, Facebook, etc - é ***aham***. Pelo que vejo, é a grafia mais comum.

Já oralmente, escuto com mais frequência as interjeições abaixo. Todas servem para expressar que você concorda com algo, ou que entendeu alguma explicação (coloquei as grafias que já encontrei para as mesmas):

- ***aham***: pronuncia-se mais ou menos como "ãrram" ou "ãrrã" (quando se quer ser mais enfático, dizemos mais pausadamente e prolongando as sílabas: "ããrraam").
- ***humrum***: pronuncia-se mais ou menos como "um-rum" ou "urrum". Em alguns casos a pronúncia pode ser mais rápida e omite-se o `m` - nesse caso, fica mais parecido com um grunhido do que com uma palavra propriamente dita (tanto que dá pra "dizê-lo" sem sequer abrir a boca).
- ***ãããm***, ***hmmm***: acredito que seriam formas reduzidas das 2 expressões acima. Mas estas são mais usadas no sentido de "Entendi" do que no de "Concordo".

---

**PS:** sou de São Paulo e a resposta acima vale tanto para a capital quanto para o interior. Em outros estados (não conheço todos) também escutei expressões iguais ou similares, mas não lembro de ter escutado alguma muito diferente disso.

Comment: Muito louco, não? Também nunca tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: A divergência de representações escritas para esse elemento de oralidade.

Comment: Talvez não haja uma maneira "correta" de escrevê-las simplesmente porque não são palavras oficiais (nem devem estar no dicionário), daí a variedade de formas escritas. E como na internet tem de tudo, achei uma [análise sobre qual seria a melhor forma de escrever *aham*](http://pseudolinguista.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/como-escrever-aham-e-um-dilema.html)

Answer (score 2):

Aqui na Bahia a gente usa humrum com o mesmo significado de aham.

Answer (score 2):

Usamos todas estas expressões em nossa região, Capela do Alto Alegre, Pintadas, Mairi, Várzea da Roça no centro oeste da Bahia. Em meu romance Noite em Paris que publico no blogue de mesmo nome se fala muito estas espressões.

Answer (score 1):

Sou do Piauí e aqui as pessoas usam unrum ou anram para concordar e un_un ou an_an para negação. Ouvi unrum entre falantes de espanhol do México.

Answer (score 0):

Eu e minha namorada estávamos tendo essa reflexão agora, daonde será que vem essa expressão? ( uhum), acredito que seja uma adaptação verbal de aham, visto que a troca da vogal tônica, a, pela u, facilita ainda mais o uso da expressão de forma falada. Jiu