# Do Portuguese people say "sim"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

In Brazil the word *sim* ("yes") is rarely used; to answer a question in the positive you instead repeat the verb:

> — Você gostou do filme? (Did you like the film?)
>   — *Gostei.* ("I liked (it)", not "yes".)

Just wondering if the same is true in Portugal, or would Portuguese people be more inclined to say *sim*?

Comment: Eu uso _sim_ naturalmente no Brasil. O seu uso não me parece nem um pouco raro.

Comment: Obligatory Ronaldo quote: «[SIIIIIIIM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhDXk8i8Qug)».

Comment: GMA, looking at @Romildo 's observation, I wonder whether *gostei*-type answers loom disproportionally large in your perception just because their equivalent are uncommon in English?

Comment: No Brasil, mais comum do que repetir o verbo é usar *aham* ([ou alguma de suas variantes](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4551/797))

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn’t say *sim* is rare in Portugal, but then how rare is rare? That said, in your example, simply *gostei* would be the most common answer in my experience, followed by *sim, gostei*. This will often be the case in questions of the type, *do/did someone do X?*

> — Falaste com o João hoje?  [Did you speak to João today?]
>   ― Falei.
>
> — A Ana está em casa? [Is Ana at home?]
>   — Está.

Or in *já*- and *ainda*-questions:

> ― Ele já chegou? [Has he arrived yet?]
>   ― Já. [Already = yes, he has.]
>
> ― Ele ainda cá está? [Is he still here?]
>   ― Ainda. [Still = yes, he is.]

A *sim* will be more likely if you go on to elaborate, especially with long verbs:

> ― Regressas já no domingo? [Are you coming back Sunday already?]
>   ― Sim, trabalho logo na segunda-feira

A *sim* will also  be common when answering questions of the type *would you like […]* in formal situations. Imagine a restaurant:

> ― Desejam ver a carta dos vinhos?
>   ― Sim, se faz favor.

Even in informal situations;

> ― Queres que te compre o jornal? [Would you like me to buy the newspaper for you?]
>   — Sim, se fazes favor.
>   [Also:] — Quero. Obrigado.

Also when you combine several questions in one:

> — Regas as plantas e dás comida aos peixes?
>   — Sim, não te preocupes.

*Rego e dou* wouldn’t work out very well. Other situations where a reply including *sim* would be very common:

> — Ele não veio?! Mas ele disse que vinha, não disse?
>   ― Sim, disse.
>   [But also simply:] Disse.
>
> — Pedi para o convidares, mas tu não o convidaste.
>   ― Convidei, sim!
>   [But also:] ― Convidei, convidei!
>
> — Naqueles tempos a vida era muito dura.
>   — Ah, sim! A juventude de hoje nem faz ideia.
>
> — Amanhã temos pouco tempo. É melhor fazer a feijoada já hoje.
>   — Sim, até porque a feijoada fica melhor de um dia para o outro.
>
> [For the umpteenth time:] — Mas vens mesmo ao jantar amanhã?
>   — Sim, já disse que sim.
>   [Or:] — Venho, já disse que venho.

Comment: I feel like I've also heard a decent bit of just "é", presumably shortened up for "(o que dizes) é assim/isso"

Answer (score 2):

Sim.

Here's the several types of answers I might expect:

> - Gostei.
> - Sim.
> - Sim, gostei.
> - Gostei, sim.

Comment: But I imagine the bare "sim" only in an unenthusiastic answer as in "sim... it was alright".

Comment: Or enthusiastic "Sim" (Sure! I really liked!)

Comment: @sumitani, I never heard a bare "sim" as an enthusiastic answer in Portugal. An enthusiastic answer would be "adorei", "gostei imenso".

Comment: I have heard the enthusiastic "sim", and it feels right for me: «- Queres que traga uns profiteroles *daqueles*? - Sim!!!»

Comment: De alguém com mais de 5 anos?... Eu tb esperaria _Quero!_, _Quero, traz!_, _Sim, quero/traz_ ou _Quero, sim_. Só sim soa muito lacónico.

Comment: Eu não vejo problema com ser lacónico... mas ok, percebo o que querem dizer.

Answer (score 0):

*Sim.*

It's used in many situations, furthermore as for the example you gave a Portuguese answer would be

> Sim, gostei.

Answer (score 0):

In some regions of South of Brazil, yes. We can just answer a question like this with a simple "sim".

But, when I do that, my friend of Sao Paolo find it a little bit funny.